# Order creation not working through rest api in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

I am using `Magento 2.1.6 CE` and also am using default `rest api's` for create mobile app. In that I follow below steps to create an order, But order is not created.

Step 1:- Create an empty cart for customer using `POST /rest/V1/carts/mine/`

[image]

Step 2:- Add product to cart using `POST /rest/V1/carts/mine/items`

[image]

Step 3:- Get cart totals using `GET /rest/V1/carts/mine/totals/`

[image]

Step 4:- Get Shipping methods by customer address id using `POST /rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id`

[image]

Step 5:- Add billing and shipping address using `POST /rest/V1/carts/mine/billing-address`

[image]

Step 6:- Set shipping information using `POST /rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information`

[image]

Step 7:- Set payment information and create order using `POST /rest/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information`

[image]

**Note:**

Am tried `PUT /rest/V1/carts/mine/order` method also but it returns following error.

[image]

How can I get this done?

Please suggest me is there any default options available to done this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to create order using api.

**Order Place:**

```
<?php
require_once 'api.php';

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../abstract.php';
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$resource = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

// The URL to your Magento 2 instance (ending with /index.php/rest/V1)
$api_url = 'site_url/index.php/rest/V1';
// Set the integrations access token.
$token = 'auth_token';

$magento = new MagentoClient($token, $api_url);
$json = $_POST['json_obj'];
$json_cart_array =array();
$json_cart_array = json_decode($json,true);
$cart_id = $json_cart_array['cart_id'];
$payment_method = $json_cart_array['payment_method'];
//$payment_method = $json_cart_array['payment_method'];

// Create customer cart using customer id.
$ordered = $magento->placeOrderCust($cart_id, $payment_method);
$result1 = json_decode($ordered, 1);
//print_r($result1);exit();
```

**API Class:**

```
<?php
class MagentoClient {
  public $bearer_token = 'auth_token';
  public $base_url = 'magento_base_url';

  public function __construct($token, $base_url) {
    $this->base_url = $base_url;
    $this->bearer_token = $token;
  }

  public function request($endpoint, $method = 'GET', $body = FALSE) {

    // Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->base_url . $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

      $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->bearer_token;
    if ($body) {
      $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
  }

  public function getProduct($product_id) {
    return $this->request('/products/' . $product_id . '/', 'GET');
  }

  public function createCart() {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/', 'POST');
    // var_dump($this->request('/guest-carts/', 'POST'));
    // die;
  }

  public function addToCart($cart_id, $product_sku, $quantity = 1) {
    $order = array(
      'cartItem' => array(
        'quote_id' => $cart_id,
        'sku' => $product_sku,
        'qty' => $quantity,
      )
    );
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/items',
      'POST',
      json_encode($order)
      );
  }

  public function addToCartCust($cart_id, $product_sku, $quantity = 1,$options) {
    if(isset($options['extension_attributes']['configurable_item_options']) && $options != '' && count($options['extension_attributes']['configurable_item_options']) > 0){
      $order = array(
      'cartItem' => array(
        'quote_id' => $cart_id,
        'sku' => $product_sku,
        'qty' => $quantity,
        'product_option' => $options
      )
    );
    }else{
      $order = array(
      'cartItem' => array(
        'quote_id' => $cart_id,
        'sku' => $product_sku,
        'qty' => $quantity
      )
    );

    }
    //json_encode($order);

    return $this->request('/carts/' . $cart_id . '/items',
      'POST',
      json_encode($order)
      );
  }

  public function setShipping($cart_id, $shipping) {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/shipping-information',
      'POST',
      json_encode($shipping)
    );
  }

  public function setShippingCust($cart_id, $shipping) {
    return $this->request('/carts/' . $cart_id . '/shipping-information',
      'POST',
      json_encode($shipping)
    );
  }

  public function placeOrder($cart_id, $payment_method = 'cashondelivery') {
    $payment = array(
      'paymentMethod' => array('method' => $payment_method)
    );

    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/order',
      'PUT',
      json_encode($payment)
    );
  }

   public function placeOrderCust($cart_id, $payment_method = 'cashondelivery') {
    $payment = array(
      'paymentMethod' => array('method' => $payment_method)
    );

    return $this->request('/carts/' . $cart_id . '/order',
      'PUT',
      json_encode($payment)
    );
  }

  public function getPaymentMethods($cart_id) {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/payment-information', 'GET');
  }

 public function createCustCart($cid)
 {
     return $this->request('/customers/' . $cid . '/carts', 'POST');
 }

}
```

This code is available on `github` but now i forgot the link. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I use the above code in api call please explain in detail

Comment: You can create write this script in magento root directory and check this is working or not in browser by accessing first script. Or you can check api using individual function from the class for creating cart, adding shipping address etc..

Comment: I am got following error
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\mage5/../abstract.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage5\place-order.php on line 6

Comment: Below error also Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mage5/../abstract.php'

Comment: create `scripts/orderapi` in magento root and put above two scripts `orderapi`  folder.

Comment: same error occurred again

Comment: may be content-deploy will help. give proper permission to files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64938/discussion-between-vignesh-bala-and-nitin-pawar).